# Entity properties access based on user role

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm developing a Spring MVC webapp using also spring security. So each authenticated user has a specified ROLE.

Based on this ROLE a user can modify only a subset of entity properties.

Now I'm trying to reach this by using spring security tags in views and mapping unmodifiable field with input type hidden, based on role of logged user. But I think that it will become a nightmare soon!

As a simple example, I do something like this (Admin can modify all, User can modify only value1 and Guest cannot modify):

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
    Value1: <input type="text" name="value1" value="${entity.value1}" />
    Value2: <input type="text" name="value2" value="${entity.value2}" />
</sec:authorize>
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')">
    Value1: <input type="text" name="value1" value="${entity.value1}" />
    Value2: ${entity.value2}
    <input type="hidden" name="value2" value="${entity.value2}" />
</sec:authorize>
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_GUEST')">
    Value1: ${entity.value1}
    Value2: ${entity.value2}
    <input type="hidden" name="value1" value="${entity.value1}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="value2" value="${entity.value2}" />
</sec:authorize>
```

What alternative approaches can I take in order to keep things as simple as possible?

Thank you
Marco

Comment: Can you show couple examples?

Comment: I've added simple example code

Comment: Just as a comment - be aware you also have to double check if only permitted fields were modified in backend too, otherwise malicious user may forge the form POST request and add fields that were not originally displayed in the form.

Comment: I know.. this is another reason why my solution is not good. thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use  `hasAnyRole([role1,role2])` to check a list of role  .Then your codes will become :

```
  <sec:authorize access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN' , 'ROLE_USER')">
       Value1: <input type="text" name="value1" value="${entity.value1}" />
    </sec:authorize>

    <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_GUEST')">
        Value1: ${entity.value1}
       <input type="hidden" name="value1" value="${entity.value1}" />
    </sec:authorize>

    <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
         Value2: <input type="text" name="value2" value="${entity.value2}" />
    </sec:authorize>
    <sec:authorize access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER' , 'ROLE_GUEST')">
        Value2: ${entity.value2}
         <input type="hidden" name="value2" value="${entity.value2}" />
    </sec:authorize>
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. I know that exists such function, but it still not change the way the job is done, that is by using input type hidden. I'm searching for another idea to avoid using input type hidden and the check expression in the view.. and also to avoid the problem explained by Kresimir Nasek in previous comment: be aware you also have to double check if only permitted fields were modified in backend too, otherwise malicious user may forge the form POST request and add fields that were not originally displayed in the form